# На каком основании стоит запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятая-перед-тире

Фраза из школьного учебника:

***Вот ребенок схватил игрушку, — тотчас по чувствительным нейронам пошли сигналы о результатах деятельности***.

Не могу разобраться, почему стоит запятая перед тире. А вы, совы, как думаете, почему?

Comment: Вот схватил - один момент, а затем пошли сигналы - другой момент времени. Если запятую не ставить - то как-будто это про один момент времени речь идет. Без тире тоже можно обойтись. Но можно и оба знака - тогда больше экспрессии в происходящем.

Comment: Можно да разрешено?  Нет, так не пойдет, сэр)) Здесь все очень строго, у каждого знака своя функция.  Хочется приблизить правописание к точной науке, а то у нас много слишком лирики и неопределенности в оценках)   Это так, не правда ли?  Вот, к примеру, экспрессия - это же отчасти семантика.   А где же остальные принципы пунктуации (грамматика, интонация)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что это **единый знак**:

*Вот ребенок схватил игрУшку, — // тотчас по чувствительным нейронам пошли сигналы о результатах деятельности.*

Ни запятой, ни тире не достаточно, чтобы выразить нужную семантику, грамматику, интонацию. **Пауза** выдержанная, не присоединительная, но при этом **повышение** голоса перед паузой.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149171/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.